# Redirect of domain works but not pages

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

In my web.config, I have several rules working fine. I have the one below and it's second in my priority. The domain redirects fine. But, www.olddomain.com/aboutus redirects to www.newdomain.com/newpageaboutus. I need it to redirect all requests to the static page at www.newdomain.com/newpage.

```
            <rule name="olddomain.com" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^.*olddomain\.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.newdomain.com/newpage" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have created a test demo on my side, it will not auto add the aboutus  if I enabled the redirect rule. Do you have another other rule which will modify the redirect url?

Comment: This was my error. My redirect from one host to the other included the newpage link. Sorry. However, I think in the future, adding stopProcessing="true" would have resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm gald you have found the reason, if you solved the issue, I suggest you could post the solution as the reply and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was my error. My redirect from one host to the other included the newpage link. Sorry. However, I think in the future, adding stopProcessing="true" would have resolved the issue.